# How to take an input and run it a code in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that responds to user input by keyword and I'm early into development. I want to take user input not as a string or integer but as just plain python and to be able to spit that back out.
here's the line that i have for input:

```
    userword=input("->")
    print("userword")
```

Say the user input is "blue". blue is a variable that is blue=function[3] (function being a list). How can I take the user saying blue as the variable blue not as a string "blue"?

Comment: Edit the question with what you have done till now.

Comment: sorry didn't know it would post immediately

Comment: I think, a file would be a good option to do that. Make user write in the file. And then read it.

Comment: is there any way to do it without external files

Comment: I guess you want to `eval()` the input. Or maybe `exec()`

Comment: This is almost certainly *not* what you want to do. What problem are you actually trying to solve? This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)